# Excel macro for coloring cells depending on the difference of the value of the cell with another cell and appearing the row in another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have an excel file with 2 columns of percentages. The first column has theoretical values of an experiment and the second column has the real values that were measured in an experiment. I want to create a macro which will be able to compare the values of the cells for every row(2 cells every row since we have 2 columns) and when the difference of the percentage is more than 5 units then I want to color the row and appear it in another pop-up or excel sheet! and this process has to be for every row. SO finally I want to have another sheet in excel which will have all the rows which had bigger difference than 5!

Can you please help me ??

Comment: This is two different questions. 1) Colour cells depending on values - any search for conditional formatting will put you in the right direction. 2) Move cells to different sheet dependent on cell differences - this isn't a code for me service, try recording a macro, copying and pasting, then google `VBA if statements` and `VBA loops` and post back if you run into difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

you shoukd be able to apply conditional formatting formula. E.g. if your columns are A and B your formula would be =ABS(b1-a1)<=0.05

As for the other sheet. You could use the same formula in an if statement and drag down. E.g. if (abs (sheet1!b1-sheet1!a1)<=.05, sheet1!a1, "") . you could then filter this sheet to remove the blanks.